# Using class from import references in view MVC.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm not sure the title is the right title to write but i don't think on better title.

After many searches I did not find a solution.

I'm new at MVC.NET.
I built a web application and added a dll reference and I want to use it in view.
I successed to use the class I built within the view.

The model:

```
using Mydll;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyWebApplication.Models
{
    public class myClass
    {
        public VaultsOnServer vaults { get; set; }
        private MFilesServerApplication oServerApp = new 
        MFilesServerApplication();
        private MFServerConnection oVaultConnection = new 
        MFServerConnection();
        private Vault vault { get; set; }

        public bool checkIfLoginAccountExist(string i_Username)
        {
            LoginAccount loginAccount = null;
            loginAccount = 
            oServerApp.LoginAccountOperations.GetLoginAccount(i_Username);

            return loginAccount != null ? true : false;
        }

        public VaultsOnServer getAllVaults()
        {
            vaults = oServerApp.GetVaults();
            return vaults;
        }
    }
}
```

The Controller:

```
using MyWebApplication.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Mydll;

namespace MyWebApplication.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    myClass myclass= null;
    User user = null;
    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Home/Login.cshtml");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CheckUser(User objUser)
    {
        VaultsOnServer vaults = null;
        bool ifUserExist = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid && InputValidation.onlyLetters(objUser.Username) && InputValidation.checkPassword(objUser.Password))
        {
            if (objUser != null)
            {
                if (myclass== null)
                {
                    myclass= new myClass();
                }

                ifUserExist = mfiles.checkIfLoginAccountExist(objUser.Username);
                if(ifUserExist == true)
                {
                    user = objUser;
                    vaults = myclass.getAllVaults();
                    Session["Vaults"] = vaults;
                }
                return View("~/Views/Home/ChooseVault.cshtml", vaults);
            }
        }
        return View("~/Views/Home/Login.cshtml");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(VaultOnServer vault)
    {
        if(user != null)
        {
            return View();
        }

        return View();
    }
  }
}
```

The view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CooseVault";
}

<h2>CooseVault</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div id="formCheckUser">
        <fieldset id="loginAccount">
            <legend id="loginTitle">Choose Vault</legend>
            <select id="dropdownOne" name="dropdownOne">
                <option value="">--pick--</option>
                @foreach (var item in )
                {
                    <option value="@item" selected="selected">@item.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

In the controller i sent in function CheckUser to view an object from class type in dll(Mydll) and i want to use with class type in the view.

can i do that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by 2 ways //First better

1) Create another class in web app and convert dll class to your web app class and use it in view as @Emad sayed

```
public class VaultsOnServerViewModel
{
    //some props
}

return View("~/Views/Home/ChooseVault.cshtml", new VaultsOnServerViewModel(vaults));
```

2) add dll reference to view by adding namespace in webconfig of views folder // do not do this

```
<add namespace="Mydll" />
```

then you will able to use in view

```
@model Mydll.VaultsOnServer
```

and

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

3) also you can use dictionary or SelectListItem to do this

```
return View("~/Views/Home/ChooseVault.cshtml", vaults.Select(s => new SelectListItem() { Text = s.Name, Value = s.Value}).ToList());
```

and in view

```
 @model List<SelectListItem>

@foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <option value="@item.Value" selected="selected">@item.Text</option>
                }
```

or use DropDownListFor helper

Comment: It's impossible to convert dll class.
You mean to make copy of the class?
If not please explain more.

Comment: @tal_sshh,  you may copy not all of your dll class, copy only that things that needed in view. In ChooseVault view you need only value and name, also your can use SelectListItem without creating class

Comment: @tal_sshh, please check the third way.

Comment: vaults not contain the option select.

Comment: @tal_sshh please provide definition of VaultsOnServer and what list you want to use in your select list show data or whats properthy are list? why are you need this object (VaultOnServer) and what is in it?

Comment: The dll is from campany.
The definition of VaultsOnServer is collection of object and it's not inherit from List or enumerable. 
VaultsOnServer contain some properties like name etc.

Comment: @tal_sshh, your vaults property in MyClass it's not a collection, maybe some property of VaultsOnServer is has collection?

Comment: vaults is a class that hold many classes.
For example, Apples a;
class Apples is contain two properties: int count, Apple b;
It's like list but without the list functionality.

Comment: @tal_sshh, whats collection from VaultsOnServer class your want to loop in view?  foreach (var item in )
                {
                    <option value="item" selected="selected">item.Name</option>
                }

Comment: @tal_sshh, so that means than you need replace "VaultsOnServer vaults = null;" by List<VaultsOnServer> vaults = null; and your myclass.getAllVaults(); should return List<VaultsOnServer>

Comment: @tal_sshh, or acording to your example, Apples should contains List<Apple> b not just Apple

Comment: I already try to replace VaultsOnServer to List<VaultsOnServer> but it's doesn't work.
The first issue is that i can't to add the dll that i added in reference to view.
I think The company that write the dll disable this option, they can do this?

Comment: @tal_sshh, nope, they can't. Now use third method. Replace s.Name and s.Value by a properthies of your VaultsOnServer class

Comment: Ok.
So i can i have GetEnumerator method and i used that but it's steal not recognize the parameter.
In the cshtml page the first line is @model IEnumerable<VaultsOnServer>
but VaultsOnServer is an error The type or namespace name 'VaultsOnServer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @tal_sshh, use @ model IEnumerable<Mydll.VaultsOnServer> or convert it in controller when returning view return View("~/Views/Home/ChooseVault.cshtml", vaults.Select(s => new SelectListItem() { Text = s.Name, Value = s.Value}).ToList()); and in view use @ model List<SelectListItem>

Comment: It's not working. :(
Thanks on your attempts, but I'll check with the company of the dll how can i use the dll.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, yes, you can.

Know that each view in MVC has an object associated with it called a model. A model is an object of whatever type you like and can be sent to the view via controller. So the controller creates an instance of the model and passes it to the view and the view can use the data in the model to, you guessed it, view the page.

For that you first declare in your view that what type of model it uses. You should put this line at the top of your `.cshtml` file

```
@model MyNamespace.MyModelType
```

then in other locations in the view you can use `@Model.MyModelPropertyOne` to access properties of the model and use them.

Finally you should pass in an instance of `MyModelType` to the view from the controller:

```
return View("Login", new MyModelType());
```

This is the outline of what you need to do if it's not clear please tell me and I'll try to explain more.

Comment: "MyNamespace" you mean MyWebApplication and "MyModelType" you mean mydll?

mydll it's not really my dll,  anyway I tried what you suggested and I get an error message "The type or namespace name 'mydll' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: `MyNamespace.MyModelType` is the fully qualified name of the type in your `mydll`.